# Auto enter password for SCP

Tags: ssh, solaris, scp

I will make scp be on cronjob so I would rather use to auto enter the password of the other server.

`sshpass -p 'your_password' scp user@abc.com:/usr/etc/Output/*.txt /usr/abc/`

This script didn't work for me, I am using Solaris.

Please also indicate an explanation on the answers. Thank you.

*ADDITIONAL*

I used

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

spawn bash -c "scp /apps/DASHBOARD/xx/xxx/xxxx/TEST1.*.txt dash@MYSERV:/apps/DASHBOARD/xx/xxx1/"
expect "*Password:*"
send "pass123\r"
interact

spawn bash -c "scp /apps/DASHBOARD/xx/xxx/xxxx/SAMP1.*.txt* dash@MYSERV:/apps/DASHBOARD/xx/samp1/"
expect "*Password:*"
send "pass123\r"
interact
```

And I put this on my CRONJOB. This script works for me if I ran this manually but when I set this on my CRONJOB, it doesn't proceed on the second scp.

Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a keypair?

Comment: How to use that? Can I also use the `expect` function?

Comment: Hello, please help me.

Comment: If you have a new question/problem, post it separately.

Comment: Even if it's connected on my yesterday's question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use public key authentication connection in order to avoid keeping/maintain hardcopy passwords.
Copy the content of local users content of `id_rsa.pub` to the remote users `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in order to establish public key authentication connection.

If still want to use password then expect script could be made, like the following and change the expect script 2nd line to match your `user` and `server` and `MY_PASSWORD` with your password:

```
spawn scp "user@abc.com:/usr/etc/Output/*.txt" /usr/abc/
expect "user@abc.com\'s password:" 
send "MY_PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

Thanks to @pynexj at post [Link to StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651597/when-there-are-multiple-spawn-statements-in-the-expect-script-only-the-last-s) i had to modify the script as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn scp /TEST1.txt root@1.2.3.4:/root/
expect "*assword:*"
send "password\r"
expect eof

spawn scp /TEST2.txt root@1.2.3.4:/root/
expect "*assword:*"
send "password\r"
expect eof
exit
```

**Note** that if you have multiple files or patterns that need to be transferred you can also consider to use SFTP with batch mode and expect.

Comment: This works for me, I just put the location of expect where it has been installed and boom. Thanks @GiannakopoulosJ

Comment: kindly help me on my additional question please. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to keep a secret on the hard disk, you can use keys in home .ssh folder to skip password authentication. That's the way non-interactive, machine to machine, authentication, is supposed to be.

Comment: help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting that you need to place quotations around the use of regular expressions in scp, so most likely that would be your point of failure.

```
sshpass -p 'your_password' scp "user@abc.com:/usr/etc/Output/*.txt" /usr/abc/
```

Comment: Yes, but I think the main problem is there's no `sshpass` function installed in Solaris. How can I install or just call the path of that function?

Comment: You can find informatino on how to install packages on Solaris here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6MER_9.5.0/com.ibm.bigfix.patch.doc/Patch/Patch_Solaris/t_installing_pkgs_sol11.html

For you it'll be `pkg install sshpass`.